# How to format timezone having shortname Id and longName?

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime, timezone-offset

I have `timezone = "[PST -08:00] America/Los Angeles (Pacific Standard Time)"` format. And I have `time["03:00 pm"]` and `date[2018/4/22]`. I need to check if it is less than to 12 hours as per current local time.

joda DateTimeZone is not accepting this id `[DateTimeZone.forID("[PST -08:00] America/Los Angeles (Pacific Standard Time)"]`.

Any options?

Here I am looking only for a timezone option. How can I cleanly convert timezone string to timezone?

Comment: When in your title you say ‘format’, I take it that you mean ‘parse’?

Answer (score 2):

You should use only [IANA's zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), in the format `Continent/Region`. In this case, you should use:

```
DateTimeZone.forID("America/Los_Angeles");
```

Note that the name is "Los**_**Angeles", and not "Los Angeles" (there's a `_` instead of a space between *Los* and *Angeles*).

You can check all the names available by looping through the set returned by `DateTimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`:

```
for (String zoneName : DateTimeZone.getAvailableIDs()) {
    System.out.println(zoneName);
}
```

In your specific case, you should parse your string (as Georg's answer explains) or map it to valid IANA's names:

```
Map<String, String> names = new HashMap<String, String>();
names.put("[PST -08:00] America/Los Angeles (Pacific Standard Time)", "America/Los_Angeles");
```

Or use some other logic such as:

```
if (timezoneName.contains("Los Angeles")) {
    // use America/Los_Angeles
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide if you want to interpret the long or short offset. I went for the long offset as you can create a ZoneId from the long name "America/Los_Angeles". ZoneId then queries the IANA Time Zone Database - see [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#of-java.lang.String-). This test case extracts the name from the given schema.

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.Date;

public class Zone {

    @Test
    public void zoneId() throws ParseException {
        String zoneName = "[PST -08:00] America/Los Angeles (Pacific Standard Time)";
        String time = "03:00 pm";
        String dateString = "2018/4/22";

        String americaLosAngelesPST = zoneName.substring(zoneName.indexOf("]") + 2, zoneName.length());
        String americaLosAngeles = americaLosAngelesPST.substring(0, americaLosAngelesPST.indexOf("(") - 1).replace(" ", "_");
        ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of(americaLosAngeles);

        SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd KK:mm a");
        Date parsedDateTime = inputFormat.parse(dateString + " " + time);

        ZonedDateTime inputZonedDateTime = parsedDateTime.toInstant().atZone(zone);

        // compare with ZonedDateTime.now()
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks Georg for your reply.  is there any other way beside parsing(substring) zoneName ? i wish if i can avoid such.

Comment: You're welcome. There are no other ways that I knew of. As the input is somewhat redundant, it will be necessary to substring. E.g. do you want to use PST or Pacific Standard Time Zone name? You have to decide. Also, it is absolutely necessary to parse the zonename somehow. 
As

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. And in particular not when already using `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It’s so much nicer to work with and has all the functionality you need.

Answer (score 0):

One more `java.time` answer. I go for the `-08:00`:

```
    String offsetString = timezone.replaceFirst("\\[[^ ]+ ([+-]\\d{2}:\\d{2})\\].*", "$1");
    ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.of(offsetString);
```

This gives an offset of `-08:00`. If you did need a time zone, I like others would go for America/Los Angeles, this being unambiguous while the three and four letter abbreviations are not standardized, often ambiguous and often not true time zones. PST, for example, may mean Pacific Standard Time, Philipines Standard Time or Pitcairn Standard Time. However, to determine whether time is before 12 noon local time, the offset suffices and is simpler both to parse and to use.

Funnily your entire time zone string could be parsed by a `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("'['zzz xxx']' VV (zzzz)", Locale.US)` *if not* for the fact that the time zone is given as `America/Los Angeles` with a space in the city name. The IANA time zone ID has an underscore there instead. Only because of this I needed to do some manipulation of the string before parsing. Then I went the whole way and took out just the needed offset.

Joda-Time is in maintenance mode with no major enhancements foreseen, and their development team advises migration to `java.time`. Not knowing Joda-Time well, I imagine that you can translate my answer to Joda-Time if you should wish.